# How to apply transparent gradient along each segment of a curve?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, inkscape, transparency, bezier-curve

Say I have a white curve in black background:

[image]

The curve has some points cut it to separate segments. From point A in the line whose opacity is 100%, the transparency gradually increasing and then decreasing so that when it reach point B, the opacity is 100% again. The middle point of the segment, therefore, will be fadest. The longer the segment is, the fader the middle point is. This will repeat for other segments.

The idea is that when a pendulum swinging in the dark then in the extremes it is most visually clear, and its balance point is fadest, and the trajectory is gradiently going from clear to faded. I use Inkscape, but answers for other tools are welcomed, because I guess the terminology is the same.

An example is provided by @Joonas, except that the slider points to the 100% opacity points, not 0. And I don't know how to add more gradient points like that.

[image]

How can I make this effect in a curve?

<sup>Also ask [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Inkscape/comments/8qztkh/how_to_make_gradient_fading_effect_on_a_curve/?st=jifhavni&sh=614e0e65).</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Do you want a gradient that follows the path? That's what I think after reading the first paragraph after the image. Reading the second paragraph just makes me confused. Do you want to fake a long exposure photo effect in Inkscape?

Comment: Yes, I want a gradient that follows the path, but the points I mark should always be whitest. The long exposure will create this effect, is that right?

Comment: You mean they should always match whatever is behind them or something? If you make the points white, nothing in the background can be whiter than that...

Comment: yes they should match what is behind them

Comment: I don't think that is possible, even with scripts. I could be wrong though... I've never really used Inkscape. — I don't quite understand why though... Do you want to like move the streak around and see what position looks the best or use the streak on top of many other other images or backgrounds? Or can you make animations in Inkscape? — Also, making the long exposure effect in a vector application is probably not the best idea. Gimp would be better for photo manipulation (or Photoshop). — Generally speaking, taking a long exposure photo would give you the best effect.

Comment: No such feature in SVG, you could make the curve out of multiple segments like say 200 or more and get the same effect though.

Comment: @Joonas Maybe moving the streak around to see what's best? I just want to have a static image, and Inkscape can't make animation. The second paragraph is just to illustrate my point; if it's so confusing I'll remove it.

Comment: @joojaa SVG can't do this? But why not? Anyway, how to make the curve out of multiple segment? And I can switch to Gimp though

Comment: The combination of... the stroke you have there, the desire to have the points of the gradient match the background, the links to posts talking about long exposure effect and using Inkscape is what throws me off. It's hard to find the connection between these things. Maybe it would help if you could show an example image of what you want to do and we forget the application and everything else...

Comment: because the standard does not have a instructions to do so. How do you make segments you draw them in one by one (or cut the original path) either by hand or by script.

Comment: @joojaa I see. But how can I make the gradient fading effect in each segment?

Comment: @Joonas no no. Let's try again. The line has gradient transparency. From point A whose opaque is 100%, the transparency gradually increasing and then decreasing so that when it reach point B, the opaque is 100% again. This will repeat for other segments.

Comment: Oh I see... So you want to create a gradient that follows a path. So [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHkNs.jpg), right? — I did some very quick googling and it seems like it's not possible in Inkscape, but who knows. I did this in Illustrator. It has a simple toggle in gradient settings: `Apply gradient along stroke`.

Comment: Well yes and no. You can make each segment a linear gradient. Or just dont do gradients at all if you have 200 segments it loses meaning.

Comment: I don't know if this has any value to you, but I added a little something to my previous image. I drew lines going from the gradient slider from each 0 opacity point to where they land on the path. [Another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUcvM.jpg)

Comment: @Joonas yes! Exactly like that. It's just that I want the slider points to 100 opacity points, not 0. But yes it is. Thank you. Is Inkscape in general lacks features than Illustrator?

Comment: well in general inkscape has more features. Its just that it is constrained by being a svg editor and its user interface. So at the end illustrator is more relevant in its feature set. In anycase both software have a bit arbitrary features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

- Place the image
- Add a background black rectangle behind the image
- Selecting the image > From the **Transparency Panel** > **Make Mask**
- **Transparency Panel** > click the mask field to activate it
- Make a circle > fill it with a radial gradient from white to black
- Select the circle and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to duplicate, move it
- When ready > **Transparency Panel** > click back the editing area (the left square)

[image: AI MASK]

<sup>*Shamelessly copied from Danielillo's answer from [How to make multiple sneak peak holes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110790/26474)*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The SVG format has no support for a gradient along a path, and neither does Inkscape, but you can get something similar with a Mesh Gradient*, using the Create and Edit Meshes tool.

For example, here's a stroked path, converted to outlines using *Path > Stroke to Path*, then a [Mesh Gradient](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Mesh_Gradients) with 5 rows and columns was applied, and then the mesh was edited.

[image]

*Note: Inkscape's Mesh Gradients are not currently supported in browsers, so this won't display in an SVG viewed in a browser. However, that may change in time. It would still be possible to export the finished work as a raster image however, such as a PNG. Also, mesh gradients are supported in PDFs.

**Edit:**

After seeing what you did in Illustrator, there is another way this could be achieved in Inkscape, so that it would render in an SVG properly in a web browser.

The effect is simple. Place some radial gradient filled circles along a path and group them.  Group the black background and white stroke to make a mask. Bring the mask to the top of the stack, and apply the mask to the grouped gradient objects. Place it over another black background.

[image]

Comment: why can't SVG support gradient? I thought that the format is for anything computable?

Comment: @Ooker SVG does support gradients, but only gradients as a fill, not as a gradient along a path/stroke. It has never been implemented.  And the mesh gradient feature hasn't made it into web browsers yet, but that might change in the future.

Comment: but why can Illustrator do this?

Comment: @Ooker because illustrator targets PDF and PDF can do this. Once SVG supports gradient meshes well you can ask for this feature into Inkscape. Like i said if you think of any feature than form your point of view everything is a just random unless you understand what the underlying rendering target the applications targetting.

Comment: @joojaa I see. But what is the specific reason that SVG can't support path gradient?

Comment: @Ooker - you'd need to ask those who are involved in developing the SVG format as to why they never implemented a gradient along a path in the SVG standards.  We can't really answer this.  I suspect there is no reason really, it just hasn't been done.

Comment: do you know any resource for a novice like me quickly get the big picture of the formats, standards, targets, etc?

Comment: @Ooker -By the way Illustrator can do gradients along a path, however, it won't work when you output it as an SVG from illustrator, it will simply rasterize the gradient, which is not really a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Ooker SVG standards are the in remit of the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/)

Comment: @Ooker - after seeing your attempt in Illustrator, there is another way to do that in Inkscape, and for to make it actually work in an SVG. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: @Ooker the set of things that would be nice is infinitely big. Even illustrator did not support gradients on strokes before CC vesion. What standards designers have in mind is a big set of general purpose solutions where harder problems can be disected into. SVGs problem is that its no use of adding features if nobody is implementing them. The gradient mesh has been suggested its now waiting for enough browser vendors to implemnent it. Untill it does theres not much use for it. On that note you want to target PDF since your making publications and SVG does not work so well for print

Comment: @BillyKerr if possible, can you provide a detail tutorial on how to apply the mesh? I've [unlocked](http://goinkscape.com/how-to-unlock-the-gradient-mesh-tool-in-inkscape/) it, but I'm still unable to make the first step in your post

Comment: @Ooker There are tutorials for using the mesh gradient online. Just search. Then if you are still having problems, you can ask another question here on GDSE

Answer (score 0):

I finally make it:

[image]

1. Appearance of the curve: Fill: none, Opacity: 100%. Select the stroke color and click gradient.
   [image]
2. Click on the underneath of the gradient slider to add more color stops. Even stops have 100% opacity, odd stops 0%. Slide all the midpoints as close as possible to the 100% stops.
   [image]
3. To make the opacity decreases faster, between two 100 points add **two** 0 points, then push each 0 point as close as possible to one end.
   [image]

The result:

[image]

<sup>See more: [Gradients in Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/gradients.html)</sup>

Comment: I believe you need to wait 48 hours and then you can mark your own answer as the correct one. Though you may want to add `illustrator` to the tags, since you switched to Illustrator.

Comment: Thanks. What makes me wonder is that I only have 3 full opacity stops, but there are 5 in total. Do you know why?

Comment: Anyway your cheating, its an ok answer but you have changed scope. I would be much happier if youd take your original questions scope back and start this question with  no but illustrator can do this.Because you now invalidate Billy Kerrs effort. In either case you may want to present us the full problem your trying to solve instead. Tgat way we could rwally explain how you should approach your problem.

Comment: Ooker you may have two curves on top of eachother.

Comment: @joojaa but I've said at the beginning that I accept any software? Anyway, it's not that I didn't want to present the full problem, it's that I virtually didn't know any term to call it properly

Comment: @Ooker well to be honest you really want to use something like mathematica, psTricks or so...

Comment: @joojaa but they lack the focus on aesthetics

Comment: @Ooker no mathematica has very good looking default graphs, that are way better than what most graphic designers do because they would need to do so much manual work

Comment: @joojaa but can it allow mouse control on the graphs?

Comment: @Ooker Yes though it depends quite much on what you want to control. It is generally more flexible in most things, but less useful in others.

Comment: @joojaa I've asked in on Mathematica. It would be great if you can have a look at it: [How to make a gradient transparency along a curve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175694/46646)