# How to make multiple sneak peak holes?

Tags: mask, clipping-mask

To make a sneak peak hole, I make a black rectangle and an eclipse (radial gradient, one stop is white and the other stop is transparent), and mask them with clip unchecked and inverted mask checked:

[image]

[image]

But how can I make multiple holes like that? It seems that only one hole can be masked at one time:

[image]

I can't find a way to keep the fading effect of the hole with subtracting objects. I can use any software.

Comment: Have you tried editing the mask, and adding more holes to the mask?

Comment: @Danielillo I use Illustrator, but I welcome any suggestion of any software

Comment: It can be done with masking one hole at a time instead of all of them at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Photoshop:

- At the image layer > make a circular selection
- Click on the mask icon
- Activate the mask > **Menu Filter** > **Blur** > **Gaussian Blur**
- **Menu Selection** > **Load Selection** > This layer **Channel Mask**
- Press <kbd>V</kbd> to activate the **Move Tool** and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to duplicate, click inside the selection and move it.

[image: masking]

Using Illustrator:

- Place the image
- Add a background black rectangle behind the image
- Selecting the image > From the **Transparency Panel** > **Make Mask**
- **Transparency Panel** > click the mask field to activate it
- Make a circle > fill it with a radial gradient from white to black
- Select the circle and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to duplicate, move it
- When ready > **Transparency Panel** > click back the editing area (the left square)

[image: AI MASK]

Comment: I've shamelessly copied your answer on [How to apply transparent gradient along each segment of a curve?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110815/26474), hope you don't mind

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

- place your image
- add a black layer on top of that (ok, its red in the image below :)
- use the 'Eraser' tool to punch the holes. Play with the Size and Hardness values until it looks about right. Then just click around with the Eraser (<kbd>E</kbd>) to punch holes in the top layer mask.

[image]